# Почему не работает сложение?

Tags: javascript

Есть тег span: `<span class="uk-text-bold more-part">0/span>`

И есть вот такой js код

```
                   var interval = setInterval(function () {
                      var b = document.querySelector(".more-part")

                        b.textContent + 5;
                    }, 500);
```

Почему не происходит сложение?

Comment: `b.textContent = +b.textContent + 5;`

Comment: Происходит, просто вы результат сложения нигде не используете

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var interval = setInterval(function() {
  var b = document.querySelector(".more-part");
  var add = Math.floor(Math.random() * 999) + 1;
  console.log(add);
  b.textContent = +b.textContent + add;
}, 500);
```

```html
<span class="uk-text-bold more-part">0</span>
```

Comment: хм... а как сделать, чтоб к b.textContent прибавлялось рандомное число от 1 до 1000?

Comment: @Евгений Что в контексте данного вопроса означает "хм..."? Недоверие, сомнение, восхищение, восторг?

Comment: хм... ну не буду же я сразу писать "а как сделать....":))) Хм-просто)) но точно не недоверие или сомнение) все ок)